# Why is the residue $\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z=\pi/2} \frac{z}{\cos z}$ not $0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm supposed to get the residue of the function $\dfrac{z}{\cos z}$ at $z = \pi/2$.

Here is my solution:

\begin{align*}
\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z=\pi/2} \frac{z}{\cos z}
&= \frac{1}{(m-1)!} \lim_{z \to \pi/2} (z-\pi/2)^m \frac{z}{\cos z} \\
&= \frac{1}{(1-1)!} \lim_{z \to \pi/2} (z-\pi/2)^1 \frac{z}{\cos z} \\
&= (z - \pi/2) \frac{z}{\cos z} \biggr|_{z=\pi/2} \\
&= (\pi/2 - \pi/2) \frac{\pi/2}{\cos (\pi/2)} \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

But the answer is supposed to be $-\pi/2$. Is my formula wrong? Or is it not a pole of degree $1$? I don't understand.

Comment: Could you please use MathJax to format equations? In its current form it is hard to read your equations.

Comment: How much is $\cos(\pi/2)$? Can you divide by that?

Comment: I took the liberty to format your question using **MathJax**. Next time, please use MathJax to format your question so other users can read it more easily. Also, division by zero error is the root of many, many troubles.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_\limits{z\to \frac {\pi}{2}} \frac {z(z-\frac {\pi}{2})}{\cos z}$

$\lim_\limits{z\to \frac {\pi}{2}} z\frac {(z-\frac {\pi}{2})}{\cos z}$

The limit of the product is the product of the limits.

$\lim_\limits{z\to \frac {\pi}{2}} z = \frac {\pi}{2}$

Which leaves
$\lim_\limits{z\to \frac {\pi}{2}} \frac {(z-\frac {\pi}{2})}{\cos z}$

We could use L'Hopital's rule, or we could do something like...

$\lim_\limits{z\to \frac {\pi}{2}} \frac {(z-\frac {\pi}{2})}{\cos z} = \lim_\limits{z\to 0} \frac {z}{\cos (z+\frac \pi2)} = \lim_\limits{z\to 0} \frac {z}{- \sin z} = -1$

$(\frac \pi2)(-1) = -\frac {\pi}{2}$

Comment: Oh i see, I didn't realize that the denominator was also 0, when i saw (z-π/2), I disregarded the rest of the equation. I was careless. Thank you so much.